# maple: How to show two lines on each other in a plot?

Tags: plot, maple, linestyle

I am plotting two functions, which have very little difference from each other.
When plotting with maple, considering my precision (12 digits), the plot shows one line. I know this is normal, but I want to show both lines as below:
the first one with red color (for instance) and the second one on the first on with blue color and a dashed linestyle.

Does any one know how I can do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The first way displays both with a single call to `plot`.

```
plot([x^2, x^2+0.1], x=-4..4, color=[red,blue], linestyle=[solid,dot]);
```

[image]

This second way produces each separately and then displays then together. (Your two curves may come from two different plotting commands, and not just from `plot` say.) As you can see the end result looks the same as from the first way above.

```
P1:=plot(x^2, x=-4..4, color=red, linestyle=solid):
P2:=plot(x^2+0.1, x=-4..4, color=blue, linestyle=dot):
plots:-display(P1,P2);
```

[image]

The various values for the `linestyle` option are any of solid, dot, dash, dashdot, longdash, spacedash, or spacedot. Details of this kind of thing can be found on the [plot,options](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot/options) help-page.